# If we run out of battery and then charge iPhone, will it turn back on?

Tags: ipad, iphone, battery, charging

I just called by my lawyers 133 times for some very important message. My iPhone is just 3 meters in front of me being charged.

Finally my lawyer come to my apartment and we both saw that the iPhone is fully charged but not turned on.

I thought charging iPhone would automatically turn it on.

I did more research. I found out that most people have the opposite problem.

[Why does my iPhone turn on when I plug it in to charge?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38715/why-does-my-iphone-turn-on-when-i-plug-it-in-to-charge)

People are complaining about the iPhone keeps turning on and  I have the opposite problem.

Actually how does iPhone officially behave? If I charge it, should it be turned on by itself?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because it significantly changes the focus of the question. It is a valid point though, but please use the "Ask Question" link on top to ask a new question (and include a link to this question here for reference).

Answer (score 1):

When an iPhone is plugged in, it will boot up (that is actually a common techniques used for restarting an iPhone if the power button doesn't work for some reason).

If the iPhone is powered off while charging, it will remain powered off and will not automatically come back on.

I understand that you have an iPhone 4 and there is the chance that it was having trouble receiving calls unrelated to the power. However, if the phone was powered off when you checked, that is the simple answer as the cause of the missed calls.

Comment: Where can I see this is documented? What kind of design force people to charge cell phone and then wait a few minutes and then do something again just to keep the iPhoine turn on? How to keep the iPhone on just by charging?

Comment: If you physically turn off the phone while it is charging it will turn off and stay off, but keep charging. If you plug it in when it is already off, it will turn on and remain on so long as it has external power or battery left. If this is not happening for you, you might have a problem with your phone. There were recalls for battery and power button issues in some recent iPhone models, but I thought this was for the 5, not the 4...

Comment: @JimThio, dr.nixon is very correct. Here are some links regarding the iPhone's power state: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107010/will-iphone-4-turn-on-automatically-when-charging, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38715/why-does-my-iphone-turn-on-when-i-plug-it-in-to-charge. (I couldn't find a specific Apple KB article regarding the behavior.)

Comment: @JimThio, note this [document which could be a little informational to you](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201569).