# How to make iPhone turned on after charging

Tags: iphone, sleep-wake, battery, charging

I often charge my iPhone when it ran out of battery. I often postponed charging my iPhone until it really run out of battery.

After I charge my iPhone, I usually go to sleep or rest or forget about it. Unfortunately, as shown in [If we run out of battery and then charge iPhone, will it turn back on?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157403/if-we-run-out-of-battery-and-then-charge-iphone-will-it-turn-back-on?noredirect=1#comment185734_157403), things tend to go wrong.

The iPhone can be fully charged, but not turned on at all. So For 3-4 hours, I would receive no incoming calls.

If I want to receive incoming calls, I could go back to my iPhone 3 minutes after charging and explicitly turn it on. However, after that 3 minutes, I usually have other things to do or is sleeping. So I am often forget to do so.

This has cost me a lot of money because I often lost important call because of this.

How do I change iPhone behavior so that charging the iPhone automatically turn it on?

I think it's just common sense. We want our iPhone to get turned on all the time and if we do not like it, we can always turn it off. The idea that my iPhone can be charged without me being able to receive any call bothers me a lot.

Comment: By "turned on", do you just mean "powered up" or also "logged into the SIM card and the carrier network"?

Comment: I mean able to receive call. What does powered up or logged into the sim card mean?

Comment: Do you need to enter a PIN for your SIM card after restarting your phone?

Comment: I want to be able to receive call from my iPhone

Comment: Depending on your settings you'll have to unlock your SIM after each restart of your phone in order to place *or* receive calls. So if you restart your phone (try it if you don't remember), do you have to enter a password/PIN to unlock it afterwards?

Comment: The simple answer is don't let it run flat in the first place. It's not good for the battery either.

Answer (score 1):

In a word: Yes.

To the best of my knowledge, the mere act of plugging-in the dead iPhone to a recognized charger will cause the phone to initiate the boot sequence once the battery has charged sufficiently to allow for running the phone and charging simultaneously.

You can check this behavior by turning your phone off and then plugging it into a known-good charging system.  You should see the *apple* appear shortly and the phone will proceed to boot-up.

Comment: Yes, the only times I've seen an iOS device not power up as soon as plugged into a power source (provided a sufficient level of charge has been reached) has been when the charger and/or cable were not Apple-certified. Or perhaps the charging connector was somehow damaged.

Comment: Exactly!  That is precisely why I used the phrases "known-good charging system" and "recognized charger" in my answer. ;-)

Comment: The phone is smart enough to know if it was deliberately shut down, or dead by battery drain, so whatever behavior the phone comes up after being deliberately powered-off and plugged in does not necessarily mean it'll do the same if plugged in after battery drain.